Analysing torque due to gravity in about an offset axis
So I started studying Newtonian mechanics, and was watching the MIT OpenCourseware videos about it. I am still struggling to grasp the concept of torque, and in one video (link here), there is a discussion of the torque about a certain axis of an object in a gravitational field. What I don't understand is this suggests that if we analyze the system with the reference frame and origin positioned somewhere outside the object, and have the object be subject to gravity, a torque that is non-zero is present. I understand that if we analyze around an axis through the CoM there would be no torque, but why is the torque present with respect to an external axis if we apply a force at the CoM, and why doesn't the object start rotating about that axis in this case?

It certainly will be rotating about that axis! Just not in a uniform way. Rotation about an axis means you are changing your angle relative to that axis. Here are two different motions of an object relative to an external axis. See how the angle relative to the two coordinate directions is changing, even if the object is moving straight up? There for we may not have rotation relative to an axis fixed to the center of mass when we apply a force at the center of mass, but we will certainly have rotation relative to some external axis.



I understand that if we analyze around an axis through the CoM there
would be no torque, but why is the torque present with respect to an
external axis if we apply a force at the CoM, and why doesn't the
object start rotating about that axis in this case?

The COM does have an angular acceleration about that axis.
There is no torque due to gravity about the center of gravity, COG, which is the same as the COM if the force of gravitational field is uniform throughout the mass.
But gravity can produce a torque about a point or axis other than that located at the COG. See the figure below. There is no torque due to gravity about the COG (point A), but there is a torque about the point B. Note that while there is no rotation about A, since the net torque is zero, there is angular acceleration of A (the COG of the object) about the point B.
Hope this helps.


It is easy to understand if we remember that torque is the derivative of angular momentum $\vec L$ with respect to time. And by definition $\vec L = \vec r \times \vec p$ can be no zero even if the object is not rotating. For example, if the object moves with a constant velocity, but the origin is not in the straight line of this velocity.
In the case of torque, $\vec \tau = \vec r \times \vec F$. If the origin is not in the straight line of the force passing by the body, then the cross product is not zero, (if the force is not zero, what happens for gravity).
